# Assembler CPI and BLTR converting to ASCII

Tags: assembly, ascii, device

i have some problem with converting my assembler hexadecimal number to ASCII. I need it bsc later i must display it on Butterfly, i need to display two digits as ff.

Here is part of code:

```
;r25 is set to 255 = 0xff
ldi r18,15
mov r19, r25
and r19,r18 ;now in r19 i got 0x0f

clr r18

mov r20,r25

lsr r20
lsr r20
lsr r20
lsr r20  ;now in r20 i got 0x0F
```

Anyone knows how to now onvert my r19 and r20 to ASCII characters? I know i should use CPI and BLTR but on idea how to do it.
Thanks for help.

Comment: One possible logic is: `if (x > 9) add_offset_to_make_it_A else add_offset_to_make_it_0`. I trust you can implement that.

Comment: @Jester x = my register right? So

cp r19,9 ; Compare registers r11 and r12
brge addoffA
...
addoffA:

And here i dont know what to do, some advice please?

Comment: Add a number that makes letter `a` from `10` (that is obviously `'a' - 10`). Otherwise add a number that makes digit `'0'` from `0` (that is obviously `'0'` itself).

Comment: Could you show me how to write just 1 condition? 
I mean when im jump from BRGE 
addoffA: What here help :D

I will be really thankfull.

Comment: Come on, surely you can add a number to a register? Something like `ldi r18, 'a'-10; add r19, r18`.